# Open Source parametrized/multi-dimensional caching tile server

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, tiles, mapnik, cache

For a project I am looking at setting up a caching tileserver using open source components. Point data is arriving from an external source and gets stored in postgis. This data has a datetime and clientid field in addition to the geometry data.

I would like users (using an open layers webapp) to select a timeframe (and clientid) for which to visualise these points. But since data traffic and repeated map requests will be high, I fear that just doing this with a WMS server will slow things down. A caching tileserver on top of my WMS could solve this. But what I don't know is if there are any tileservers out there that are aware of additional dimensions (parameters) beyond x/y/z.

I am currently looking at mapnik/mod_tile (skipping the WMS step), mapserver/mapcache and geoserver/geowebcache but am not restricted to these at all. Custom development on top of FOSS components is ok too (but I hate re-inventing the wheel).

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GeoServer/GeoWebCache by adding [parameter filters](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/layers.html#parameter-filters) in the layer tile caching configuration, enabling selected lists of values for time/elevation/cql_filter (whatever you use to perform dimensional selection).